convert .bin to .img using makefile
I was writing a simple bootloader,
I am using this make file command to convert the main.bin to a main_floppy.img
cp -f build/main.bin build/main_floppy.img

but I keep getting this error
nasm src/main.asm -f bin -o build/main.bin cp -f build/main.bin
build/main_floppy.img process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, cp -f
build/main.bin build/main_floppy.img, ...) failed. make (e=2): The
system cannot find the file specified. make: *** [Makefile:3: setup]
Error 2


CreateProcess, "system cannot find the file specified" - so running on Windows. There is no cp command in Windows.

It is usually the case that "how do I do X with make / with a makefile" is the wrong question.  The right one is typically how to do the job using command-line commands for the command interpreter that make is to employ.  And on Windows, at least, you cannot neglect the "the command interpreter that make is to employ" part.

Looks like you're running Windows.
Try this instead:
all:
   nasm src\main.asm -f bin -o build\main.bin 
   rename build\main.bin main_floppy.img

If you're indeed running Linux (we don't know), try this:
all:
   nasm src/main.asm -f bin -o build/main.bin
   mv build/main.bin build/main_floppy.img

(I just splitted the two commands in two different lines)

Sorry i forgot to provide my makefile code, I edited your code a bit:
setup:
nasm src/main.asm -f bin -o build/main.bin
rename build/main.bin main.img
But i get this error now
nasm src/main.asm -f bin -o build/main.bin
rename build/main.bin main_floppy.img
The syntax of the command is incorrect.
make: *** [Makefile:3: setup] Error 1

If you're running windows, you need to use backslashes (""). Forwardslashes are interpreted as specific command line parameters from the "rename" command.

Thanks! Finally its working after 4 days. i was scared to use stackoverflow lol. Your much better than most other people on stackoverflow, Pretty rare!

Alright, thanks so much, glad to have helped! would you mind to just close the question as solved?

Sure thing! I marked it as solved
